# How to get syslinux to install to fat32 backup boot sector

Tags: fsck, syslinux, fat32

How do you get syslinux to install to fat32, and have it write the backup boot sector. It only writes to the main boot sector, and then fsck.fat complains. You can get fsck.fat to fix it, but this requires running it in interactive mode, and hence is not possible from a script.

```
/tmp # fallocate -l 50m test_image
/tmp # mkfs.fat -F32 test_image   
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/tmp # syslinux --directory syslinux --install test_image

/tmp # fsck.vfat test -a
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  3:53/6d, 4:59/6b, 5:53/66, 6:4c/73, 7:49/2e, 8:4e/66, 9:55/61, 10:58/74
  , 90:fa/0e, 91:fc/1f, 92:31/be, 93:c9/77, 94:8e/7c, 95:d1/ac, 96:bc/22
  , 97:76/c0, 98:7b/74, 99:52/0b, 100:06/56, 101:57/b4, 102:1e/0e, 103:56/bb
  , 104:8e/07, 105:c1/00, 106:b1/cd, 107:26/10, 108:bf/5e, 109:78/eb
------------ SNIP ---------------------------------------------------------
  , 484:0d/00, 485:0a/00, 504:fe/00, 505:02/00, 506:b2/00, 507:3e/00
  , 508:18/00, 509:37/00
  Not automatically fixing this.
test: 2 files, 353/100792 clusters
```

Comment: Why was this down voted? It's a clear question, with steps to reproduce the error. It resulted in a good answer. 

Downvoting without a comment to explain why is bad form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system :

*For FAT32 file systems, the reserved sectors include a File System Information Sector at logical sector 1 and a Backup Boot Sector at logical sector 6*

Which means that you can fix the issue by invoking these two commands (replace `sdXX` with your partition, e.g. `sdb1`):

```bsh
sudo dd if=/dev/sdXX of=bootrec.dat bs=512 count=1
sudo dd if=bootrec.dat of=/dev/sdXX bs=512 seek=6
```

In case you're working with a disk image file, you **must** add `conv=notrunc,nocreat` parameters at the end of the second command or otherwise you will truncate and destroy the image.

I've tested the commands and they result in fsck.vfat being totally happy.